# Gatling: Using userId from the Session API

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I want to use a userId from the Session API inside my test. I could find this comment on the userId: "The userId is a simple sequence and is unique across users."
It will work perfectly for me if it's a simple sequence since I want to use it as an index to get items from a collection.
So let's say I have a simple scenario where I inject 5 users:

```
setUp(myScenario.inject(rampUsers(5) during (10.seconds)).protocols(httpProtocol))
```

How is the userId going to be assigned to those 5 users? Will each user have id starting from 1 in the following manner:

```
user 1 - userId = 1,
user 2 - userId = 2,
user 3 - userId = 3,
user 4 - userId = 4,
user 5 - userId = 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch it from *Session*. But pay attention - you can't extract it as *Gatling EL* (nevertheless you can set into *Session*)

```
    .exec { session =>
      println("userId - " + session.userId)
      session
    }
```

Comment: Will it always start from 1 and be sequential? I am not concerned about the order of ids, for example it might be 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, but it's important for me that all numbers are present, starting from 1 till 5.

Comment: @IhorVolkov yep, it's a value which will just increment and will be sequential